# How can I prove that being the functions $g_{ij}$ from the class $C^r$ on $U$ is independent on choosing the local coordinate system ???

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I want to define a Riemann metric using the functions $g_{ij}$ on local coordinate system $(x^1,x^2,...,x^n)$ on $U$ and functions $h_{ij}$ on local coordinate system  $(y^1,y^2,...,y^n)$ on $U$ and I have managed to understand the relationships between the functions $g_{ij}$ and $h_{ij}$.

How can I prove that being the functions $g_{ij}$ from the class $C^r$ on $U$  is independent on choosing the local coordinate  system ???

Comment: What is the relationship that you understand?

Comment: @FriederJäckel how I can express functions $g_{ij}$ in term of $h_{ij}$ and the function $h_{ij}$ in term of $g_{ij}$

Comment: but how? could you please inform us about this relation and the set $U$ and the manifold you're working on.

Comment: You need to start with the definitions of $g_{ij}$ and $h_{ij}$ and relate them using the chain rule.